# MATLAB - temporarily checkout git commits within script

Tags: git, matlab

### Use case

I'm performing data analysis with MATLAB. For this I use software-library that is under source control (and in the MATLAB path). This software is changing from time to time, so it would be preferable to have the same version of the code base when using old scripts.

### Current workaround

Currently I'm noting down the commit/hash of the version I'm using as a comment to be able to change to it, if somethings doesn't work. This is annoying and an automatic solution would be better.

### Desired solution

Here is some mockup-code, how the solution should look like.

```matlab
cd path/to/library
git checkout 497e8527b6bdea4981d025937c8ce3d84ba038f8
cd /current/script/path

... % some matlab code

cd path/to/library
git checkout master
```

### Questions

- Can anyone give me a hint to a possible solution?
- Is there maybe an even better solution? (in other IDEs one can require a special version for a programm etc. - didn't found anything similar within MATLAB)

### Links

[MATLAB documentation for source control](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/source-control.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) - didn't found a good hint in there.

Comment: The problem with this is that if your MATLAB code is terminated prematurely (canceled by user, error generated, computer crashes, light goes out, ...) then your git repository will not be restored to master. I think maybe it would be better to install the toolbox to a version-specific directory, then `addpath` that specific directory in your MATLAB scripts.

Comment: Oh, haven't thought about that problem @CrisLuengo. :/
I like your idea but guess it is not feasible, as there are new commits all few days and that would mean lot's of version-specific directories. But at least for the major versions, I will use that.

Comment: But you only need an installation for each of the versions used in your scripts. How many scripts are there? And not all commits introduce breaking changes. Also, maybe your scripts shouldn't always be written to use the current master version, but some specific earlier version that has all the features that the script needs. I guess it all depends on specific situations and goals.

Comment: Yep, thought about that as well... I guess I will give that workaround a try. 
Do you know a git-command to 'dump' a commit into a new folder? But I guess once a week, I could do this manually.

Comment: I would write an install script, as part of your repository, that installs the toolbox. If it's just M-files, it can be a simple `cp *.m` command (or `copy *.m` on Windows). The script can generate the destination directory name based on a git tag or commit hash.

Comment: I imagine this git repo uses tags? You should put your MATLAB code under source control, and perhaps have a utility script which injects the latest tag version of the other repo in your MATLAB code somewhere

Comment: Sadly no tags for not major versions (and not under my control). :/

Comment: @Laenan "git command to dump a commit into a new folder:  `git archive <commit> | tar -x -C path/to/folder`